# How to fix the "An Error Occurred Retrieving Content" error in Hearthstone in Linux?

Tags: technical-issues, linux, hearthstone, wine

I am currently trying to run Hearthstone on Linux and it went fine, I installed with wine, I can log with my profile but right on the screen with the "Play game" button i get the following error:

```
Wooops! We are having problems loading some content, Please try reloading this page using the button below. Thanks!
```

And I get a link to this: 
https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/BLZBNTBNA000003E8?utm_source=App&utm_medium=other

I tried some of the solutions but is not working out... Can someone give me some idea about that if he has any experience with this ;?

Thanks to everyone!

EDIT:
Some people fixed is by installing lib32nss-mdns but it is for amd processors, so anyone knows a version of that for intel?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is for amd processors"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Well, check this out http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lib32nss-mdns - It needs architecture amd64 (:

Comment: That does not mean AMD processors, that means [64-bit processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well I did not knew, amd64 really looked like it should be AMD... xD Thank you for this, but I have tried it and it did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it! I have done a lot of things so I do not really know which one fixed it, but here is what I have done:

- Removed Wine and all its files (so this means removal of everything about the game)
- Reinstalled Wine and updated to the newest version (note that apt-get update did not get me there I had to install it myself -- And I have Wine sources! --)
- Installed battle.net app and then Hearthstone using this guide: http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Play-Blizzard-s-Hearthstone-Heroes-of-Warcraft-on-Linux-424410.shtml (Wine version which I updated to is mentioned)

And it magically worked.

Notes: I tried installing it via Playonlinux but this created some extra issues and problems so I prefer not to use it. I tried a ton of things which made it for other people but nothing worked for me. So if you do not have time to search and try minor solutions you can try my brutal approach. {:

Thanks to everyone who lost their time reading this!